# UISearchBar crashes with NSRangeException

Tags: swift, uisearchbar

I came across this bug in my app and apparently it also appears on many other apps especially Apple apps like Music, News...
If you use the search function on these apps, type something into it, then double click the search bar to bring up the text selection cursors. Hold the first cursor and drag it to the left or right without exceeding the last cursor. Keep holding the first cursor and type something on the keyboard, the app will crash with the NSRangeException.
[image]

Since I use UISearchBar on my app, I have this same problem. I am not sure if this is a known bug or not but I can't seems to find any information online. Is there a work around without changing UISearchBar to something else? Also is the a way to capture touchesend  event (when your finger leave the cursor after moving it), so that I can further look into this problem, I tried the touchesend function of UITextFieldDelegate but it does not work.

Comment: Can't you just disallow text selection?

Comment: @GustavoConde It is a search box, it should work as is.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a work around. It is not a perfect fix since it does not solve the root of the problem but as far as user experience goes, it is just as good.
First you need to extend UISearchTextFieldDelegate for your SearchViewController and override textFieldDidChangeSelection and shouldChangeCharactersIn methods. Add a flag to tell you if the double cursors is active.

```
func textFieldDidChangeSelection(_ textField: UITextField) {
    if textField.selectedTextRange?.start != textField.selectedTextRange?.end {
        flag = false
    } else {
        flag = true
    }
}

func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    if !flag {
        searchBar.resignFirstResponder()

        // calculate the end position of the cursor
        let tempRangeS = textField.offset(from: textField.beginningOfDocument, to: textField.selectedTextRange!.start)
        let endPosition = textField.position(from: textField.beginningOfDocument, offset: tempRangeS + string.count)

        // replace the selected text
        if let textRange = textField.selectedTextRange {
            textField.replace(textRange, withText: string)
        }

        searchBar.becomeFirstResponder()

        // move the cursor to the end position
        if endPosition != nil {
            textField.selectedTextRange = textField.textRange(from: endPosition!, to: endPosition!)
        }
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

By resigning from focus, you effectively remove user selection which cause the crash in the first place, then you calculate where the cursor should stay after your replace the text and move the cursor there only after you set focus again.